# Identifying Facebook Events in EKEvent in EventKit on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, calendar, eventkit, ekevent

I'm using EventKit to access the Calendar store for a Today Extension.

Once I've got permission from the user I use a predicate to get all events from the users available calendars.
I have a label in my UI that shows the user the source of the event, for instance: **"Rob's Birthday found in Birthdays"**

However I'm stuck with a problem with Facebook events brought into the Calendar store from the Facebook integration in iOS.
This is the different calendar stores I want access to, their availability and the source name from EventKit:

- UK Holidays* - available - shows as 'UK Holidays'
- Birthdays - available - shows as 'Birthdays'
- **Facebook Events - available - shows as 'Calendar'**
- Personal  -available - shows as 'Personal'
- Other iCloud - available - shows with relevant name
- Google, Yahoo etc... - available - shows as relevant name

You can see the problem, why do Facebook Events just show as Calendar!
I could just presume that Calendar always means Facebook Events but that's hardly future- (or possinly even present-) proof.

Anyone got any ideas? I've po'd every property I can find on the EKEvent and containing EKCalendar objects but there seems no specific Facebook identifier.
Radar?

*I presume this changes dependant on the Locale setting of the device.

Comment: I've filed a Radar: 30723852

Comment: Didn't try, but what about `calendar.source.sourceType`, doesn't give that something useful? https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/eksource

Comment: Sadly, no :(   I tried every property I could find in class and superclass